# Unable to sort using ignoredProperties in Realm

Tags: swift, realm

I've was trying to sort an `RLMResults` using an ignored property but I keep getting this error `'Invalid sort column', reason: 'Column named '(null)' not found.'`

This following is my model

```
class Store: RLMObject {
    dynamic var key = ""
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var latitude = 0.0
    dynamic var longitude = 0.0
    dynamic var distance = 0.0

    override class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "key"
    }

    override class func ignoredProperties() -> [AnyObject] {
        return ["distance"]
    }
}
```

and this is the function that I'm running

```
func sortByDistance(currentLocation: CLLocation) {
    stores = Store.allObjects()
    let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()

    realm.transactionWithBlock { [unowned self] in
        for obj in self.stores {
            let store = obj as Store
            let storeLocation = CLLocation(latitude: store.latitude, longitude: store.longitude)
            let distance = currentLocation.distanceFromLocation(storeLocation)
            store.distance = distance
        }
    }

    stores = Store.allObjects().sortedResultsUsingProperty("distance", ascending: true)
}
```

When I tried to do `println(stores.firstObject().distance)` the default value of `0.0` gets printed in my console.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can't sort by an ignored property.
When you chose to ignore a property, the values are not stored in Realm, and it is therefore impossible for Realm to use the property in any way. So the solution is to not ignore it.
Longer term that particular distance calculation will be provided by an intrinsic query in Realm.

Comment: If that's the case, then what is the purpose of having an ignored property if it can't be used in any way? Just for clarification, I read about sorting using ignored properties here http://www.raywenderlich.com/81615/introduction-to-realm#p81615code44

Comment: It is useful when you also use the objects stand alone - outside realm, to have properties that are not stored in Realm.

Comment: The example uses an older Realm version which returns RLMArray instead RLMResults when queuing allObjects() :/ i am trying to work out the same issue, sorting by a calculated property